# Disable progress bar Matlab

Tags: matlab, progress-bar, progress

I'm using a code in Matlab composed of a large number of nested functions. A large number of these functions show `progressbars`. Is there any Matlab command or any possibility to disable `progressbars` showing, without having to locate and comment/remove all the lines where they are called from?

Comment: are you talking about this one? https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/waitbar.html

or custom text based ones?

Comment: can you explain it with a simple code which functions are showing 'progressbars'?

Comment: Are you talking about the `progressbar`  utility [in the File Exchange](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6922-progressbar)?

Comment: It is a complex code. I'm talking about a standard Matlab progress-bar evoked for example by this line of code: "reporting.ShowProgress('Rescale')". Since I'm running the code from a function I created, I want something like "warning off" but to suppress all the progress-bar outputs. Do you know any solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume from your comments you mean you have lots of functions calling `waitbar`.

You could overload the 'waitbar' function with your own `waitbar.m` ensuring its higher on the searchpath.  Although this is not usually a good idea and may cause problems in the future when you (or anyone else you uses your codes) do want to use the waitbar and it doesn't appear.

Another (preferable in my view) way to disable it is to create your own intermediate function where you can toggle on/off the waitbar:

```
function h = mywaitbar ( varargin )
  % preallocate output
  h = [];
  % use an internal persistent variable
  persistent active
  % by default set to true
  if isempty ( active ); active = true; end
  % Check to see if its a control call
  if nargin == 1 && ischar ( varargin{1} )
    % is it a call to disable it?
    if strcmp ( varargin{1}, '**disable**' )
      active = false;
    else 
      active = true;
    end
    return
  end
  if active 
    h = waitbar ( varargin{:} );
  end
end
```

The downside to this is that you will need to find and replace all your waitbar commands with the new function 'waitbar', but this is a one time only action.

Then disable all future calls to waitbar by:

```
 mywaitbar ( '**disable**' )
```

Run your codes and no waitbar will be shown.  The use of a peristent variable will keep the status until you restart Matlab (or you invoke `clear all`).  To stop 'clear all' resetting it you can use `mlock` in the function.

To reenable the waitbar:

```
 mywaitbar ( '**enable**' )
```

To test it use the following code:

```
for ii=1:10
  h = mywaitbar ( ii );
  fprintf ( 'test with waitbar %i\n', ii);
end
```

Now disable the waitbar capability:

```
mywaitbar ( '**disable**' )
for ii=1:10
  h = mywaitbar ( ii );
  fprintf ( 'test with waitbar disabled %i\n', ii);
end
```

You will see that the code above runs with no waitbar being shown.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. If I understood right, you are suggesting me to open a waitbar before the code execution in order to suppress the others. How can I do that? This command starts all the nested waitbars: total=r.GetResult('a'). What do I have to write before this command in order to suppress the waitbars? Thank you

Comment: No, thats not what I'm suggesting, save the function and run the tests I added to see how it works.

Comment: Ok but my problem is that I cannot locate each part of code where the progress-bar is initialized. What I need is to open a waitbar before the code execution in order to suppress the others. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Why cant you locate it?  You can search and replace all m files containing the text `waitbar` with `mywaitbar` using something like notepad++.   You could in theory create your own `waitbar` and set the visibility to off - that "might" work -> but if any of the child codes deletes the waitbar that will fail as the next waitbar call will create a new one.

Comment: ok thank you. I'll try